# docker mongodb configuration files Permission denied

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, permissions

i'm new in mongo and docker.

I want to make my own mongo container by custom config file from docker-mongo instructions

[image]

Make folder and config file.

[image]

and `sudo chown 999:999 /etc/mongo`

[image]

But got Permission Error.

[image]

Enter the container but can't access mongod.conf

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Just include the text itself in your question, properly formatter. This makes your questions more discoverable and more accessible to people who may not be able to see the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid access permission error, instead of sharing a volume for your .conf file.
you can add it natively directly on build.

so that you avoid permission issues

and you don't need to share volume for it on container run

Read documentation about `COPY` to do it is very easy

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/